# How to keep track of the label in supervised learning?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm

I have 144 images named "Good_id" and "Bad_id".

Now I have read all the images and extracted 13 features from them and stored in the numpy array of shape (144,13).

What I don't understand is how do I tell the classifier( I am going to use svm for this ) that images in the array are from classes Good or Bad.

Answer (score 2):

Save the classes into a separate array `y`, encoding "Good_id" as 1 and "Bad_id" as 0 (in the same order as they appear in your (144,13) array). Then when you use SVM you pass both numpy arrays, in the following way:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> clf = SVC()
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
```

(Taken from sklearn [SVM documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)).
More generally, if you have `K` different classes, you can represent them using `k` different numbers. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#multi-class-classification) is the documentation for the multi-class case.

Comment: Thanks ! So when i split the data for train and test using train_test_split,will the classes of X_train be preserved?

Comment: Yes they will be preserved.